# Setasign SetaPDF SetaPDF_Core_Text_Block / canvas->text() displays the text upside down

Tags: php, pdf, setapdf

With SetaPDF from Setasign, when importing a page from a document and trying to paint a line of text to that page the text shows up upside down, as if it was reflected on the x axis.

I tried drawing the text vía SetaPDF_Core_Text_Block() and also with the canvas text() helper

```
$reader     = new \SetaPDF_Core_Reader_File($original);
$tempWriter = new\SetaPDF_Core_Writer_File(Routes::DOCUMENT_UPLOAD.'test.pdf');
$document   = \SetaPDF_Core_Document::load($reader, $tempWriter);
$portada    = $document->getCatalog()->getPages()->getPage(1);
$canvas     = $portada->getCanvas();
$font       = \SetaPDF_Core_Font_Standard_HelveticaBold::create($document);
$text       = new \SetaPDF_Core_Text_Block($font, 24);
$text->setText('ABCDEF');
$text->setAlign(\SetaPDF_Core_Text::ALIGN_LEFT);
$text->setBackgroundColor('#FFFFFF');
$text->draw($canvas, 0 ,0);
```

The result in this image:
[image: text in pdf upside down]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setasign support provided the page in manuals to understand this issue:

https://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-core-manual/canvas/#index-2-1

TLDR;
I was working with a PDF that was previously rotated (didn't know) so when working with existing pages you have to use:

```
$pageImported = $document->getCatalog()->getPages()->getPage(1);
$pageImported ->getStreamProxy()->encapsulateExistingContentInGraphicState();
$canvas       = $portada->getCanvas();
```

So you encapsulate the content and do not work with the page original graphic state.

Comment: In your case the graphic state was rotated but there's also the page rotation which should be taken into account. This is also documented in the given link.